# Run Nuget command Update-Database for migration code first using Code

Tags: .net, nuget, entity-framework-core

I am trying to find out if its possible to run the Nuget command in c#, so I can enable migrations to be run from a application pushing a button for example.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is on the backlog: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/646, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use `DbContext.Database.Migrate()`? It would make your life considerably easier...